# Issue in Power shell script while using Ping command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read the host file and trying to ping the each host name and after that capturing the IP address in the response and trying to match with the IP address mentioned in the host file.

I have three scenarios:-

1) Its pinging the host and getting the reply back with the correct IP
Result :-Resolved and Replied
2) It's Not pinging at all and not resolving the IP
Result :-Not Resolved and Not Replied
3) It's Pinging but not resolving the IP correctly mentioned to the IP in the host file
Result :-Not Resolved and Replied

I am trying to achieve that scenario with the below script but not fully achieved as different expression need to be used.

Can someone help me to finish it

```
$lines = Get-Content myfile.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch "((^#)|(^\s+$))"}
# get all test pairs
$tests=$lines |
    ForEach-Object{
        $fields = $_ -split '\s+'
    echo " Fields are $fields"
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt $fields.Length; $i++){
            New-Object PsObject -Property @{IP=$fields[0];Host=$fields[$i]}
        }
    }

$tests |
    ForEach-Object{
        $props=@{
            IPAddress=$_.ip
            Hostname=$_.Host
            Resolve =' '
        Reply = ' '
        }



    $PingResult = ping -n 1 -w 10 $_.host 
    #echo "$PingResult"
    foreach ($line in $PingResult)
    {
    if ($line.StartsWith("Pinging") -eq $true)
    {
    $_.ip= $line -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' 
    echo "IP is $IP"
      if   ($matches[0])
        {

                $props.Resolve ='Y'
                $props.Reply='Y'
        }

      else 
                {

                $props.Resolve ='Y'
                $props.Reply='N'

                }

    }
}New-Object PsCustomObject -Property $props



}|
Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Out-File D:\CEP\testlogging.txt
```

Note:- Cannot use Test-Connection because it throws exception when server wont reply back or doesnot exist and it takes more time to ping.

Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/07/pstip-resolving-ip-addresses-with-wmi/) article from @ShayLevy can help you.

Comment: Thank JPBlanc, But i need to match the IPV4Address also to the IP address mentioned in the host file, So tahts why following the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it's too late to be of much help but this should resolve the issues you are reporting with Test-Connection.

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $IP -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

That will limit the ping count to 1 and error will be ignored. Then you can work with the object it produces instead of having to parse lines.